# Copy directory contents using 'cp' command

Tags: linux, backup

How do you copy all the contents of one directory into another?

For example:

```
$ cd /home/newuser
$ cp -a /backup/olduser/* .
```

The problem with the above is that the globing pattern '*' matches the hidden directories '.' and '..' and you end up with a directory 'olduser' inside 'newuser', as well as the contents.

You could also do something like this:

```
$ rmdir /home/newuser
$ cp -a /backup/olduser /home/newuser
```

But what if newuser already contains some default files and directories?

What is the simplest, most correct, easiest to remember and not mess-up way to move the contents of one directory to another using just the basic 'cp' command and the shell?

Comment: Great answer to this question here on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/86891/401660

Answer (score 34):

Try:

```
cp -ra /backup/olduser/. /home/newuser
```

Comment: This is great, but I can't figure out exactly how it works. I think it's probably because I don't understand how `.` and `..` work. Care to explain?

Comment: This worked for me but `cp -r ./a b` didn't. Any idea why?

Comment: works for me too, but the `r` option is not needed. The `a` option implies `r`.

Comment: the -r parameter seems to be a bit redundant at this point!

Comment: The `-a` parameter does nothing to help in this situation. The command `cp -r ./a/. b` will copy the contents, and only the contents, of directory `a` into directory `b`. The `-a` flag preserves links, timestamps etc., which is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 26):

Two directories a and b.

Both have files in.

You are in a directory that contains a and b.

```
cp -r ./a b
```

`-r` = recursively.

Comment: Don't you want -a to get all files?

Comment: The -a argument is nothing do to with all files, it's short for archive, it will preserve file ownership, permissions, access times etc. The -a argument (while highly useful) isn't a standard option, and several cp implementations don't provide it.

Comment: Yep, the version I'm using looks like this:

'cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-pvX]' with no -a option.

Comment: What about hidden `.` files?

Comment: @mch: automatically included, because you've told `cp` to copy a directory `a`, and `a/.somedotfile` is contained by `a`.  if `b` exists, this command will create an exact copy of `a` at `b/a`.

Comment: -a    Archive mode.  Same as -RpP.

Comment: Easy way: `cp -R /some/dir/* /another/dir`

Comment: This copies a/foo to b/a/foo instead of to b/foo

Answer (score 19):

Remember that, by default, `cp` copies the first directory **into** the second directory if the second exists.

For example `cp -r a b` will copy **the directory** `a` into `b`. If `b` does not exist, it will be created with the contents of `a`.

If you want to copy the **content** of `a` into `b` (for example when copying a whole filesystem into a mount point) use:

```
cp -r a/. b
```

as in the previous answer.

Please also note that `-a`, used in some of the other answers, is the same as `-dr --preserve=all` and will preserve timestamps, context and extended attributes.

Comment: How does the `/.` work?

Comment: `a/.` represents the content of directory 'a' as opposed to the directory itself, in most situation it is synonymous but when using `cp -r`, it avoids cp default behaviour (copying a INTO b).

Comment: awesome tip, this is exactly what I was looking for but failed to find elsewhere - all that 'foo/*' or '-r foo/' that fails in corner cases.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen '.' is not a wildcard at all. It is literally the "parent" directory, and '..' is the grandparent. This means '/foo/./././././.' is the same directory as '/foo', and '/foo/bar/..' is the same directory as '/foo'. Think of them as hardlinks that are builtin to the filesystem.

Comment: @quuxman thank you, I wasn't aware of it back then. I'm gonna remove my old comment to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have seriously reconfigured your shell, the globbing pattern '*' does not match '.' or '..', as you can verify using just echo *.  What it does instead do is omit files whose name begins with a '.', so your approach will miss all hidden files.  You can tweak some of this behavior with shell options, for example the dotglob option in bash, but it then won't be the portable and robust option that you are looking for.

If you need to do this more than once or twice, I recommend that you look into rsync or unison (depending on specific needs) with carefully crafted source and target specifications.

Another alternative is to put the source directory in a tarball and untar it over the existing target directory.

Comment: i use this: `( cd /src/dir ; tar cf - . ) | ( cd /dest/dir ; tar xf - )` ... the `tar cf - .` tar's the source directory, dotfiles included, and spits it to STDOUT, which gets piped to the STDIN of  the `tar xf -`.

Comment: I think the whole point of the OP is how to reference files that start with '.' but _not_ the special '.' and '..' directories. There is a far more elegant solution above instead of using rsync or some other complex program.

Answer (score 2):

This will copy both the normal and hidden files, while excluding the parent directory (`..`):

```
cd /directory/to/copy
cp -r * .[^.]* /destination/directory
```

If you do not exclude the parent directory, you end up with all of the contents of `..` in your destination directory as well.

Comment: But this still excludes names that ***begin with*** `..` (e.g., `...` or `..super-hidden`).

Answer (score 0):

To copy files that begins with a dot just do cp .* target/

So easiest is just to do the cp command two times.

As Peter Eisentraut sais normal globbing rules do not include .. and . (hm, how to end this sentence? ;)

Just use -r to make it recursive and -i to make cp ask whether you really want to overwrite a file.

```
cp -ri /backup/olduser/* /newuser/
cp -ri /backup/olduser/.* /newuser/
```

Comment: Usually `*` does not match `.` or `..`, but it does if you use `.*`.  Try `echo .*`.  You can exclude `.` and `..` with the following pattern: `.[^.]*`.

Comment: @mch: But `.[^.]*` still excludes names that ***begin with*** `..` (e.g., `...` or `..super-hidden`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for copying all the files and directories except for hidden directories recursively from the current directory to wherever:

```
cp -rf * ^.*
```